# Dulplicate / wrong uf_match entries on multisite

Tags: wordpress, user-account

I can't explain why this occurs, but I have several contacts where they have a entry for both ID 1 (parent site) and their sub-site but they are not users of domain ID 1 site.

Is this the expected behavior?

I have very few users at the parent site yet, hundreds of uf_match rows that have domain ID 1. Sometimes the domain ID is wrong for their sub-site.

I tried saving an email in Civi on a domain that is incorrect to see if that would make this occur but it did not.

So, any suggestions on what I should do for the entries that are in the wrong domain? Delete it if is a duplicate? I don't see a way to fix incorrect domain id entries other than manually doing so :/ I could run *synchronize uses to contacts function* but that probably will just add an entry and not edit the existing.

From time to time, we see a WP user without a Civi contact. Each time that user saves another record in Civi, it creates a duplicate contact of themselves. I also cannot pinpoint why this occurs at times.

Comment: Try hooking into `civicrm_pre` and testing for `$op = 'create'` and `$objectName = 'UFMatch'` to see when entries are created. If you log a backtrace, this will tell you the origin of the entries.